# Self Join using a Group By clause getting "Invalid Identifier" error

Tags: sql, group-by, self-join

I'm trying to put together a `Self Join` using a `Group By` clause to see which person is getting paid the highest in their respective jobs but I keep getting this error
`00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"`

Below is my code that I am currently trying to fix:

```
Select a.*,b.sal
From EMP a,(Select job,MAX(sal)
            From EMP
            Group By job) b
Where a.empno = b.empno
```

I did some research and I couldn't find anything that pertained to what I am doing (maybe becayse what I am doing is too simple?) but nonetheless I am looking for anything that will point me in the right direction.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The derived table `b` doesn't have a column called `empno` what is the structure of your tables and example data?

Comment: That didn't fix the problem and now the inner Select Statement isnt working and I am getting 00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: What didn't fix the problem? I didn't recommend any thing.

Comment: Oh sorry I jumped the gun, but table b has a column called `empno`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a column called `empno` that you are returning in the subquery. I think you want something like this which will return the `max(sal)` for each employee based on the job:

```
Select a.*, b.sal
From EMP a
inner join
(
  Select job, MAX(sal) sal
  From emp
  Group By job
) c
   on a.job = b.job
```

Comment: Ah okay, for some reason I thought that I could just use empno since its in the table.  A nooby mistake it was, thank you for your help.

Comment: @AdamHalegua You can only reference data that you are actually returning in your subquery.

Comment: Okay I'll keep that in mind, I originally tried to do `a.sal = b.sal` to see if that would work but I guess it didnt because I never renamed `MAX(sal)`

Comment: Yes, you have to supply an alias for the `max(sal)` column so it can be referenced as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Select a.*
From EMP a
INNER JOIN
( 
   Select job, MAX(sal) MaxSal
   From EMP
   Group By job
) b ON a.job = b.job AND a.sal = b.MaxSal
```

Comment: Ah that worked, it never dawned on me that I should try that.  Thank you for your answer.